# ngControlStatus (valid, invalid, pristine, dirty, etc.) not working on <select>

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms, control-state

I am trying to do some form validation and for some reason when I try to add a class to my select with the condition of myTest.pristine nothing happens. This works fine on a regular input however. Please see my example below.

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="hasPrimaryLanguageError && primaryLanguage.pristine">
  <label>Primary Language *</label>
  <select  class="form-control" #primaryLanguage name="primaryLanguage" [(ngModel)]="model.primaryLanguage">
    <option value="default">Select a Language...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let lang of languages">{{ lang }}</option>
  </select>
  <div *ngIf="hasPrimaryLanguageError && primaryLanguage.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking into this further I found that my #primaryLanguage was not set equal to ngModel. This has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your default value needs to be empty i.e;

```
<option value="">Select a Language...</option>
```

and also initially set

```
model.primaryLanguage = "";
```

so your final code will be

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="hasPrimaryLanguageError && primaryLanguage.pristine">
    <label>Primary Language *</label>
     <select  class="form-control" #primaryLanguage name="primaryLanguage" [(ngModel)]="model.primaryLanguage" required>
       <option value="">Select a Language...</option>
       <option *ngFor="let lang of languages" value="{{yourlanguaugeid}}">{{ lang }}</option>
     </select>
     <div *ngIf="hasPrimaryLanguageError && primaryLanguage.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Required</div>
 </div>
```